# Can I run a Fedora VM on top of XenServer / ESXi? What's the closest alternative?

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware-esxi, xenserver, operating-system

I am planning on moving to Citrix XenServer to host a couple of VM's and am looking to find out if Fedora is in fact supported. The site says it can run Red Hat, but aren't this and Fedora nearly the same?

Can I run this OS in a virtual machine on this hypervisor? What alternative OS's are there to do this?

Thank you,

**EDIT: I just looked and Fedora isnt listed for ESXi either, just Red Hat Linux. Will it run on here either?**

Apparently from the Citrix forums someone has built Fedora on XenServer 4.1, so I guess there would be no reason it wouldn't work on 5.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work, the worst case scenario is that you have to hand-crank the installation of the vm-tools - shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: It will just 'work'? Despite not being on the supported list?

Comment: Oh god yeah, LOADS of unsupported stuff just works, don't forget that a VM environment is just an emulated PC, you'd have to go out of your way to write something that wouldn't work in fact. Look at all the people on this board talking about running Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 already in VMWare/Xen/VirtualBox etc.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Makes sense. So what is the point of the list? Just the stuff they will officially support if I called them or something? the OS's that are technically possible are much more than this list, correct?

Comment: the list is things they've tested and support - also they include vm-tools for these platforms too.

Comment: Ok, well by the sounds of it, I should be ok to run a Fedora VM or two

Answer (score -1):

Fedora 10 on top of a VMWare (not esx, the free version) worked OK for more than a year. The host OS was Slackware.